# coursera-dl osx not running from the command line

Tags: python, macos, bash, pip

I am trying to run coursera-dl from the command line on OS X Mavericks.

The following is the output from the console:

```
     $ coursera-dl
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/coursera-dl", line 5, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
        working_set.require(__requires__)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
        needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
        raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: six
```

I installed it using:

```
sudo pip install coursera-dl
```

For the record I have installed the required packages and python | coursera-dl are on my path.

Can anyone make a suggestion, for what I should do?

P.S. First question on Stackoverflow!

Comment: can you `import six` from a python shell?

Comment: Yes I can from the python interpreter.

Comment: what is the last of the traceback?

Comment: The entire traceback is in the original question.
The version of `six` I have installed is 1.6.1

Comment: what does `print six.__file__`  after you import it.
 
`

Comment: `>>> print six.__file__`
Returns 
'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six.pyc`

Comment: `which python` `which pip`?

Comment: Respectively, `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/pip`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved! Here is what fixed it and the source I obtained the solution from.

```
$ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
$ sudo python distribute_setup.py
$ sudo rm distribute_setup.py
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
$ sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Found here - http://dev.imanol.me/post/65244552920/python-on-osx-mavericks

I think this proves that with enough googling you can fix a lot of problems. Though I don't know why this worked, it has.

Comment: Its nice to know I have helped one person! In hindsight I believe this was an issue around the paths used by pip vs homebrew and the links between packages. Cheers, Luke

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and quickly solved it using python3 pip. Python 2.7 pip didn't work for me (at least at this time of writing).

**Uninstall old version (if you haven't)**

```
sudo pip uninstall coursera
```

**Mac OSX (Yosemite)**

```
brew install python3
pip3 install coursera
```

**Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip
sudo pip3 install coursera
```

**Usage Example**

```
cd ~/Downloads/MyAwesomeCourses
coursera-dl -u your@username.com -p 'yourPA$SwORd' algorithmicthink2-002
```

Hope it helps.